# Slow subset of matrix by rownames in R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

From a large matrix, I only want to keep certain rows which are included in an extra vector. This vector contains some rownames of the matrix.

I used a `microbenchmark` to compare four different solutions but I would like to know if a faster solution exist in R.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(1e8), nrow = 1e4, ncol = 1e4)
rownames(m) <- paste0("row_", seq(1:nrow(m)))
dim(m); m[1:5, 1:5]
include_list <- paste0("row_", ceiling(runif(1000, 1, 1e4))) # rows to keep

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  m1 <- m[rownames(m) %in% include_list, , drop = FALSE],
  m2 <- m[include_list, , drop = FALSE],
  m3 <- m[match(include_list, rownames(m)), , drop = FALSE],
  m4 <- subset(m, rownames(m) %in% include_list)
)
```

Here are the results of the `microbenchmark`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 m3 <- m[match(include_list, rownames(m)), , drop = FALSE] 251.9575 258.0483 279.9949 266.1691 284.8803 422.3918   100   b
                     m2 <- m[include_list, , drop = FALSE] 251.5875 256.4012 275.9379 263.2740 277.1073 459.7414   100   b
    m1 <- m[rownames(m) %in% include_list, , drop = FALSE] 226.1647 229.9530 239.3308 234.0090 239.8762 305.8925   100  a 
            m4 <- subset(m, rownames(m) %in% include_list) 227.7144 230.8488 242.3036 234.8678 239.1995 388.8809   100  a
```